# Camel AmbiguousMethodCallException Abstract Classes

Tags: java, exception, apache-camel

I've got three classes

```
public abstract FoundationReport
{
    public abstract FoundationDetails getDetails();
}

public abstract BaseReport extends FoundationReport
{
    public abstract BaseDetails getDetails();
}

public Report extends BaseReport
{

    ReportDetails reportDetails;

    public ReportDetails getDetails()
    {
        return reportDetails
    }
}
```

ReportDetails extends BaseDetails, BaseDetails extends FoundationDetails.

In my camel xml I've got a section:

```
<convertBodyTo type="path.to.Report" />
        <when>
            <simple>${body.details.type} == 'myself'</simple>
...
```

However the call to body.details.type results in:

```
Caused by: org.apache.camel.component.bean.AmbiguousMethodCallException:     
Ambiguous method invocations possible: 
[public path.to.ReportDetails  path.to.Report.getDetails(), 
public abstract path.to.BaseDetails path.to.BaseReport.getDetails(), 
public abstract path.to.FoundationDetails path.to.FoundationReport()]
```

I had assumed (incorrectly) that the only concrete implementation of getDetails in the Report class would be used. Why am I getting this exception and how do I work around?

Comment: What version of Camel do you use?

Comment: We're using version 2.15

Comment: Can you add abstract to the class as well

Comment: Did that work with abstract on the class?

Comment: Ah sorry - I thought you meant add to the example provided. The class was already marked abstract as they have abstract methods.

Comment: My working theory

Because the variable I'm trying to get is named reportDetails and not details then details part of body.details.type won't resolve (or more accuratly finds 3 methods named getDetails().

If I had a method called getReportDetails then I could do body.reportDetails.type - however as this class is also used to map to JSON changes to that signature would break my JSON model. 

I'm looking for a way to reference the reportDetails variable directly without relying on a getter....I'm not sure this is possible

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*** UPDATE ***

I've marked this as the answer as this has solved my problem using the current version of camel. However Claus Ibsen's answer/bug fix will likely address this situation in subsequent camel releases.

---

I believe I've found a workaround by using ognl instead of simple - it's not pretty but it works.

I've replaced
`<simple>${body.details.type} == 'myself'</simple>`

with

`<ognl>exchange.getIn().getBody().getDetails().getType() == 'myself'</ognl>`

My thinking was that I need to access the object itself rather than rely on expected getter signatures based on variable name. It seems to work!

Answer (score 1):

Its a bug in Apache Camel. I have reproduced it, and logged a ticket to get this fixed: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CAMEL-9032